# resolve a promise within another promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, resolve

In NodeJS, I'm trying to resolve an outside promise when the resolve is within another promise. The outside resolve is called, but the inside one is not.

Why is this? Shouldn't the resolve pass down into the inner promise and resolve up the parent resolve from `new Promise(function(resolve...)`?

```
function doIt() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // resolve('resolve called!'); // This works
        Object.keys(objects).forEach(function(key) {
            return deptSettings(key)
             .then(function(settings) { 
                 ... do stuff
                 if (no more stuff) 
                    resolve('inside resolve called!'); // Not called
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: a promise can only be "completed" once (resolve or reject) ... once resolved, that's it, your other resolve's are ignored

Comment: i.e. your "inner" call of `resolve` is trying to resolve the outer Promsie, which has already been resolved by calling `resolve` in the first line

Comment: @JaromandaX right, the inner `resolve` is referencing the parent `resolve` passed in by `new Promise(function(resolve...)`, so shouldn't that single promise be resolve and shortcut the rest of whatever will be called?

Comment: @JaromandaX I see. Miscommunication. I'm not running both resolves at the same time. I just left them there to show

Comment: `resolve` isn't `return` - the function keeps going because that's what you want it to do

Comment: `resolve` or `reject` can only be called once per Promise, so you also can't use a `forEach` loop. I recommend looking into [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: no miscommunication at all - read the first comment ... the outer promise is resolved immediately ... all subsequent calls to resolve will be ignored

Comment: It's probably best if you describe what you want this code to do without limiting your explanation with ideas about how you think it should be implemented (see [*"X/Y Problem"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: clearly how you think it should work is very different to how it does work. The fact that there's a return in the forEach callback suggests a lack of understanding not limited to Promises

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, but I didn't write the loop, return function, etc, only adding the `Promise` around it.

Answer (score 4):

What you have would work just fine — for the *first* promise that resolves within your `forEach`. After that, all subsequent `resolve` calls are ignored.

It sounds like you have a bunch of things to do and want `doIt` to return a promise that resolves when they're all done. Assuming it's okay that they run in parallel, you'd use `Promise.all` for that:

```
function doIt() {
    return Promise.all(
        Object.keys(objects).map(function(key) {
            return deptSettings(key)
                .then(function(settings) { 
                    // ... do stuff
                    // Return final result (for this deptSettings)
                });
        })
    );
}
```

`doIt`'s promise will resolve when all of the promises created by the `Object.keys(...).map` resolve (or reject when the first of them rejects). The resolution value will be an array of the values returned by `Return final result` above.

---

From a comment on the question:

> so shouldn't that single promise be resolve and shortcut the rest of whatever will be called?

That suggests you want to resolve the promise *once*, based on some condition, and short-circuit the remaining work you were doing in `Object.keys`. If so, you could just remove that first `resolve` and the first `deptSettings` promise that resolved would trigger the single `resolve` of `doIt` — but there's an idiomatic verson of that, which is `Promise.race`:

```
function doIt() {
    return Promise.race(                           // Only change is here
        Object.keys(objects).map(function(key) {
            return deptSettings(key)
                .then(function(settings) { 
                    // ... do stuff
                    // Return final result (for this deptSettings)
                });
        })
    );
}
```

`race` takes an array (well, any iterable) of promises and settles (resolves or rejects) based on the first one of those that settles.

Comment: I had the first `resolve` in there just for demonstration of what was called and what wasn't. I wasn't running both `resolves` at the same time. The current code in the question shows this now.

Comment: @Growler: Do you want `doIt`'s promise to wait for all of the `deptSettings` promises and the "stuff" after, or just for the first of them (whichever settles first)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix a `forEach` loop with `Promise`. Sync and async shouldn't be mixed together.

What you can do is have an array of promises, and use `Promise.all` to ensure that all the promises in the array are resolved.

For example:

```
    var myPromises = [];
    Object.keys(objects).forEach(function(key) {
        myPromises.push(your-function-that-returns-a-promise)
    });

    return Promise.all(myPromises).then(
        // do stuff after
    );
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/config-parser/blob/master/lib/phase/flatten.js#L111-L125)